# Ionic Capacitor: Change App Name, App Icon and App Loading Screen

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

how is it possible to change the App Name, the Icon (when it is installed) and the Loading Screen?

I tries:

```
ionic capacitor run android
ionic capacitor copy
npm install capacitor-resources -g
ionic capacitor sync
npx cap sync
```

Nothing helps.

My capacitor.config.json looks like:

```
{
  "appId": "com.example",
  "appName": "Example App",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    }
  },
  "cordova": {}
}
```

Comment: Hi. I'm having the same issue. Do you happen to get the answer to this already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing appName in capacitor.config.ts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703844/changing-appname-in-capacitor-config-ts-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by @jcesarmobile:

Capacitor never modifies the user projects, so the appName and package are only used the first time you call add for the platform, after the native project is created, changes in the config won't affect the native project.

If you didn't do any changes in the project you can remove the android/ios folder and add them again, but that's not really recommended, if you need to change the app name, just edit the native project

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/configuration#changing-the-app-name

On iOS you can't really rename the app, but you can change the Scheme name

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/configuration#renaming-your-app