# Changing appName in capacitor.config.ts not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework, configuration, configuration-files, capacitor

After chaning the *appName* in `capacitor.config.ts`, I have tried:

```
npm run build
npx cap sync
```

and still not getting app name changed when installed in android!

How to change the app name then?

**Note** : This is for latest `capacitor 3`

Comment: try to delete android/ios folder and change appName/Package name then add android/ios package hope it's work

Comment: You have to eject android and IOS platform and then again add platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Capacitor never modifies the user projects, so the appName and package are only used the first time you call `add` for the platform, after the native project is created, changes in the config won't affect the native project.

If you didn't do any changes in the project you can remove the android/ios folder and add them again, but that's not really recommended, if you need to change the app name, just edit the native project

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/configuration#changing-the-app-name

On iOS you can't really rename the app, but you can change the Scheme name

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/configuration#renaming-your-app

Comment: i updated both string values.
`<string name="app_name">AppName</string>` and `<string name="title_activity_main">AppName</string>`
my app shows updated name but when in Recents screen/App Switcher it still showing old name.

Answer (score 3):

may be I am late but this will help.

You can do this by making a change in `strings.xml` file

**1) app_name and title_activity_main tags**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">myappname</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">myappname</string>
    <string name="package_name">io.ionic.starter</string>
    <string name="custom_url_scheme">io.ionic.starter</string>
</resources>
```

*Note:- Tested on ionic 5 capacitor*

Answer (score 1):

only edit file strings.xml in android/src/main/res/values and go!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that these strings and more (like appName, appVersion number and version Code) have to be modified only compiling the "capacitor.config.json" and with the command "npx cap copy"

Comment: still getting no change! Can you please elaborate more precisely!

Answer (score 0):

My answer for Google users who also searched for "*changing Android package name*".

Refer to the documentation page of Capacitor configuration:

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/configuration#changing-the-package-id

To sum up all answers and docs:

If you want to re-build APK with new **Package ID** you must edit `applicationId` in the `android/app/build.gradle` file.

Package ID **cannot be** the same on Android device. App Name can be duplicated.

```js
defaultConfig {
-       applicationId "io.ionic.starter"
+       applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
```

However, if you really need to change the **App Name** *(without re-creation of your Android project again)* you can change it by editing `app_name` value in the `strings.xml`.

```xml
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
```

<sup>**Note:** The default location of `string.xml` is `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`</sup>